# Pathfinding with 2D, non-grid based movement over uniform terrain

Tags: 2d, path-finding

I'm looking for the best solution to pathfinding in my game. The map is ultimately grid-based, but entities are positioned using floats, and can move in any direction to any point on the map. The 'ground' in my game has a uniform movement cost, but of course there can be obstacles that block the way. The majority of obstacles will be static, and although there will be other animate entities in the game, I *may* get away with not considering them - it's an isometric *Theme Hospital* style strategy game, so no fighting.

Most of the path-finding articles I've seen cover 3D or grid-based 2D movement. Any suggestions for something that might cover my use-case? Many thanks.

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer right now, but you might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054701/how-to-use-the-a-path-finding-algorithm-on-a-grid-less-2d-plane.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called the "any-angle pathfinding problem."  You basically have two choices:

1. Generate a [navigation mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh) for your map and search over that using A*

   [image: Navigation mesh]
2. Search over a grid using an algorithm meant specifically for any-angle pathfinding.  Traditionally, the way to do this was A* + path-smoothing *(linear interpolation, etc)*, but these days a more popular alternative is [Theta*](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/jair10b.pdf), which is easier to implement, runs faster, and produces better results than path-smoothing.

   [image: Theta* vs. path smoothing]

All of the above methods generate *near* optimal results.  If for some reason you **need** optimal results, [this paper](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICAPS/ICAPS13/paper/download/6060/6194) was released a few weeks ago.  I haven't had a chance to read it yet, though, so I don't know how efficient it is, or how difficult it is to implement.

Comment: Great, thanks! I have no need for totally optimal results, as long as it's close.

Comment: Just thought I'd add [this article](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/theta-star-any-angle-paths/) to the ones you listed. It seems like a more succinct version of the paper you linked, by one of the original paper's authors. I think I'm gonna go with Theta*, cheers.

Comment: Link does not work. Please update answer.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the modern era, there's a really nice "Empirical Comparison of Any-Angle Path-Planning Algorithms" from 2015, here: http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/socs15a.pdf Specifically, Sub-2, Block A*, and ANYA are interesting contenders, depending on your needs.