# Overlaying grid for pathfinding

Tags: path-finding, grid

My game is not grid-based, so units can be at any arbitrary coordinate and move at different speeds. My obstacles are all rectangular and axis-aligned, so naturally it makes sense for me to overlay a grid over the map for pathfinding. Each unit will take up a grid cell (floor(unit.x / CELL_SIZE), floor(unit.y / CELL_SIZE)). I will then run standard A* grid-based pathfinding on the grid.

The problem is that although the path is grid-aligned, the unit movement is not. Thus, in the midst of moving, the unit might end up colliding with a cell that is blocked, and get stucked. Here's a picture to illustrate:

[image: picture]

I'm trying to get from point A to point B. B is the center of the grid cell, since it is a waypoint from the found path. A is the point the unit is currently at. The pathfinder thinks A to B is valid movement, since it takes the grid cell of A as the start point and the diagonal neighbour B is not blocked. But moving from A to B might result in position C, which is blocked.

I thought of using a soft collision radius for pathfinding, but it has its problems. The pathfinder will not return any paths where there's a soft collision. So if the current location of the unit already has a soft collision, the unit cannot move! It seems that it is necessary to keep the pathfinding collision and physics collision **identical**...

How do I resolve this problem, and what is the standard way to overlay a grid for pathfinding?

Comment: don't allow diagonal movement...

Comment: @ratchetfreak But diagonals reduce the number of grid cells that need to be searched, and I'm trying to make pathfinding as speedy as possible. Also, I believe A* on grid is usually done using 8 octants, so I'm sure there's a standard solution out there! Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: A* doesn't impose limitations on the graph; only on the heuristic

Comment: It's common to do a ray cast or a sphere sweep to ensure the path is clear. You can save processing time by only doing those checks on diagonal movements.

Comment: @Byte56 So I would do the check during the A* pathfinding itself, when expanding any diagonal neighbour? Does this mean my A* would have to run on the exact coordinates instead of the grid coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you'd do the check during the pathfinding itself. In your example you're working with both exact coordinates and grid coordinates. I see no problem with keeping the first coordinate exact and later coordinates grid coordinates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pathfinding with 2D, non-grid based movement over uniform terrain](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58963/pathfinding-with-2d-non-grid-based-movement-over-uniform-terrain)

Comment: @Wakaka As Danny has linked, a good solution to this problem is to not use a regular grid for A*, but instead use a navigation mesh that conforms around your obstacles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to only allows a diagonal movement in the graph you use for pathfinding if both of the corresponding vertical and horizontal cell are clear.

In your case, since C is not clear, you should no be autorized to go from A to B directly.