# A* pathfinding in 3D

Tags: 3d, path-finding

I've looked through some A* pathfinding algorithm examples, but as far  as i know they work with grids  e.q -> http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

But how can I use this algorithm in my 3D Engine(I'm using Unreal Engine 4)?

Comment: You overlay a 2D grid on the 3D world. Look at how the A* project in Unity does it. Btw, A* isn't limited to grids only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually A* does not use dimensions.

A* works with **nodes** and each nodes have paths to other nodes.

In the case of a 2D grid every cell is a node and every boundary is an **implicit path** (left, right, up, down, and/or diagonals), the key here is that it is implicit.

This is a trick to reduce the memory footprint, but A* itself does not require a 2D or 3D grid. You can use A* with **explicit paths/connections** between the nodes such as a country road map.

In the case of a 3D grid, you apply the same method as a 2D grid but now you can move in the 3rd dimension as well.

But this is not how most 3D games use A* because the memory needed for a usable 3D grid becomes too large very quickly. Instead they use **navmesh**es.

Search the web for "**navmesh**"

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh

Blue part is the navmesh:

[image]

A* works on those: each triangle is a node, each edge is a path.

There isn't an up-down-left-right, there are neighboring triangles through edges A-B-C.

Comment: will be the center of a triangle used as point for the pathfinding?
and is this done with some kind of earclipping to get this navmesh?

Comment: The edges of the triangles are the connections, the triangles are the cells.
Once a coarse path is found through the triangle/cells the path is usually refined (straightened, smoothed) while still being within the triangles.

Here's a related question that shows path smoothing examples: (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81593/a-star-pathfinding-and-discrete-smooth-positions)